# autocomplete not a function in materializecss if I refresh the browser; but hard refresh loads properly

Tags: jquery, materialize

I dynamically pull content from an api endpoint to use as part of my auto complete drop down

```
var autocomplete_fields = {}
get_all_cats()
    .done(function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data['results'].length; i++) {
            autocomplete_fields[data['results'][i]] = null;
        }
        $('#source').autocomplete({
            data: autocomplete_fields
        });
    })
```

Now, while this works fine if I hard refresh (command + shift + r) a normal refresh would result in:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
```

I made sure that things run only after everything's loaded by wrapping everything under

```
window.onload = function () {
   /// all my other stuff is here
}
```

Any idea why this is happening or how to approach debugging this?

Stringified variable:

```
{"test":null,"doge":null}
```

Comment: I removed my answer... I didn't now about an autocomplete function in Materialize. But I found this short example [**here**](https://codepen.io/tofanelli/pen/ZOqNNO). --- Can you console.log and post the content of `autocomplete_fields` using `console.log(JSON.stringify(autocomplete_fields));` ?

Comment: Yes, that's the example I followed to implement this. It worked fine on an older version of materializecss but since upgrading it has stopped working consistently. I've updated my question to include the autocomplete fields.